# Can't install arm64 package

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I'm trying to install some arm64 libs for cross compiling

```
sudo apt-get install uuid-dev:arm64
```

returns

```
E: Unable to locate package uuid-dev:arm64
```

despite having run

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
sudo apt-get update
```

[You can see that the package exists for arm64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/uuid-dev), but it's not finding it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no download mirrors listed at [Download Page for uuid-dev_2.27.1-6ubuntu3_arm64.deb on machines](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/arm64/uuid-dev/download). The uuid-dev package for arm64 architecture appears to be unavailable from the official Ubuntu uuid-dev package download webpages for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following to "sources.list". Alter the distro vresion.

```
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates main restricted
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial universe
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates universe
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial multiverse
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates multiverse
   deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem that OP is/was having in 2017 since they are on an End of life release.